# Chances of acceptance for proceedings?

Tags: authorship

I am a graduate not in education. I gave a talk at a conference which was well recieved. My studies dont match those of the forum as much as otherd so I was surprised to be invited. Now I've been invited to submit an article to the conference proceeding (which are digital). Previous editions had 10-14 papers. There were 33 presentations at the conference. It was my first presentation and if successful it will be my first publication. But what do you think my chances are?

Comment: It depends on what you write, of course. But 50% according to the numbers you give. No one can really give you an answer here. Write a good paper.

Comment: Do you know how many of the 33 presentations resulted in invitations to submit an article?  That information would influence my estimate of your chances of acceptance.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Not to mention how many of the invitations resulted in submissions on previous occasions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time and means to do so and you are interested in this opportunity, I would suggest doing it; it does not hurt and as someone who used to work in Higher Education, it was not out of the ordinary for scholars from other fields to contribute to conference proceedings (just as you presented at this conference) because Education as a discipline is inherently understood as multidisciplinary in scope. None of us can necessarily give you your chances without assessing the strength and merit of each person who would also be submitting. The positive news is that if you write something that you feel good about, if it is not accepted, provided there are no limitations imposed by the organization that hosted the conference, you still nonetheless have a publishable work in your pocket that can ostensibly be sent to journals for publication.